# Adding fadeIn() in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add fadeIn() in my code, tried some possibilities but not working for me. Could you please let me know where should I place fadeIn()? all other possibilities ? Why only those would work? Code Here.
https://codepen.io/ma-halepoto/pen/aqOWXQ

```js
//loading DOM before any other execution.
$(document).ready(function() {
  // making callback function to make a grid.
  $("#sizePicker").submit(function makeGrid(e) {
    // emptying the table for fresh-reload.
    $("table").empty();
    // Pulling out input numbers.Storing them in block-scop unchangable variables.
    const height = $("#inputHeight").val();
    const width = $("#inputWeight").val();
    //creating rows+appending. 
    for (let r = 1; r <= height; r++) {
      $("table").append('<tr></tr>');
      //creating columns+appending.
      for (let c = 1; c <= width; c++) {
        $("tr").last().append('<td></td>');
      }
    }
    //preventing grid from vanashing.    
    e.preventDefault();
    //calling event on pixelCanvas for/to click to listen action of accepting color on each coloumn.
    $("#pixelCanvas").on("click", "td", function(event) {
      var color = $("#colorPicker").val();
      $(event.target).css("background-color", color);
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: to fade() what ?

Comment: like this ?`https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bLVBNX

Comment: @TemaniAfif yea exactly...Thanks for quick reply

Comment: it's not me but @CarstenLøvboAndersen ;)

Comment: What is the function of .hide() ?
Why it is necessary to attach to $("table").empty().hide() ?
Why would not only fadeIn() works ?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry...hey Thanks alot @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: @Mahe no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fadeIn` will only work if the item isn't visible.

eg:

```
$(selector).hide().fadeIn()
```

In your code you can change

```
$("table").empty()
```

to

```
$("table").empty().hide()
```

then when you've built the table:

```
$("table").fadeIn()
```

If you do `$("table").show().fadeIn()` or just `$("table").fadeIn()` without hiding it (either with `.hide()` or `.fadeOut()`) then it's already visible and does nothing.

You could use fadeOut with a callback, eg:

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
    
    $("#eg").fadeOut(function() {
        $("#eg").text("updated text");
        $("#eg").fadeIn();
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='eg'>some text</div>
<button type='button' id='btn'>click me</button>
```